# Apex code for inline style

Tags: oracle-apex

```
<a href="#" class="lvl0_ico1" style="background: url("DynamicImage Loading Code Here") no-repeat  0  0;">
```

What is the apex code for adding a background image to an element? I don't want           to use any css class names for this.

Answer (score 0):

If the element is one report column, you can define the "link Text" such like `<img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#edit_big.gif" alt="">`  in column link part. 
Or you can define it in the pl sql statement such like "

```
  case 
      when #P1_Test is not null then '#IMAGE_PREFIX#menu/pin_32.gif'
     else ' '
     end test_monitor  "
```